# SQL Server Backend, Access front end connection question

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I transferred my Access Back-end to SQL Server and linked the tables. I used the SQL Server Migration Wizard. When I ran my Forms, Reports and Queries, I was surprised to see that it worked perfectly fine as if I did not even migrate.

How is it the JET SQL syntax of Access able to retrieve data from SQL Server which uses T-SQL language?

Answer (score 0):

Because Jet doesn't need to use Transact-SQL, it just knows how the data is stored, the same way you can use an ODBC connection to pull data from an Oracle database without using PL-SQL. Also, you can write a stored procedure in the SQL database, using T-SQL, and you can fire it off via Jet: the proc lives and runs on the SQL side, and Jet doesn't need to know how it works, just how to fire it.